# SPSS Cloud can't open/create temporary file

Tags: spss-modeler, watson-studio

When running a flow in Watson Studio that runs perfectly fine on SPSS Modeler Desktop, I get the following error:

```
> Failed to open/create file
> "/opt/IBM/SPSS/ModelerServer/Cloud/tmp/63E-7FE52328A7C0-5829-4-D.bin"
```

What can I do to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

could you provide the stream and how to reproduce your error?
as i know, modeler flow on watson studio has some different representation than desktop verison

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply. I already got an answer from the Modeler development team, saying that the problem is that the virtual disk Modeler's server is running on is getting full.